# How to use local xml saved in my project??

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Hey the server which i am using is too slow to respond while using Maps, so i decide to ship my xml with the app and storing it locally in the app. How should i go about using it??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not properly implemented the `pathForResource`:

```
NSString * string = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource"@"list-50.xml" ofType:@"xml"];
```

This is wrong.

So it should be

```
NSString * string = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"list-50" ofType:@"xml"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"xml"]` to get the path. From there you can use NSData, NSString, or other classes to load the data.

Comment: i did this: NSString * string = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource"@"list-50.xml" ofType:@"xml"]; and then NSData * data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentOfFile:path]; but its giving me nil i have saved the file in my project and copy it to the destination folder

Comment: Don't use `@"list-50.xml"`, just use `@"list-50"`. The `.xml` comes from the `ofType:` part.